# how can I calculate order of an element in finite field using ntl?

Tags: element, ntl, finite-field

I'm trying to calculate order of an element in finite field (Group) using ntl. but I did not find any function to do this!
can anyone guide me please?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no built in way to do this.

But you can write a script yourself.
A field `F` has two operations, addition (`+`) and multiplication (`*`). First you have to specify if you want to know the order of an element `g` in the group `(F,+)` or the group `(F \ {0}, *)`.

1. Find the order of `g` in `(F,+)`:
   This is the easy case, since the order of every element in this group is p, if the field has p<sup>m</sup> elements.
2. Find the order of `g` in `(F \ {0}, *)`:
   This is a litte bit hard. The order of `g` in `(F \ {0}, *)` is also called the [discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm). Basicly you can try g<sup>k</sup> for every k=1,...,p<sup>m</sup>. But this will take a while. A simple way would be the [baby-step giant-step](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) algorithm. 
   I have never tried it, but you may also take a look at [this discrete logarithm implementation](https://github.com/onechip/dlog) using NTL.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear AbcAeffchen,Actually I Knew that, this function is ready (inbuilt) in Sage , Pari/gp and Magma, those are using NTL library. somehow I have to get answer in NTL with reliable way (coding!). Right now I'm trying to call their function in C/C++ and use the result, this one is not easy task!

Comment: If you want to compute the discrete logarithm just using NTL, you should take a look at the Baby-step giant-step algorithm. it is simple and there are groups, where no faster algorithm is known.